# How do I copy all files to a sub directory based on the file name?

Tags: bash, shell, cp

I am sure this is possible with a bash script, but I want to make sure I'm not missing something obvious.  Google hasn't been much help, so maybe you can be.

Assume a directory has the following files

```
dir/file1
dir/newfile2
dir/oldfile3
```

I would like to figure out the best solution for copying all files in the folder to a folder 2 levels deep based on the first two letters of the filename, so the result would be

```
dir/f/i/file1
dir/n/e/newfile2
dir/o/l/oldfile3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
cd dir
for file in *; do
    newpath="${file:0:1}/${file:1:1}"
    mkdir -p "$newpath"
    cp "$file" "$newpath"
done
```

Be sure all your filenames are two chars or more, though.

`${var:n:m}` is simply Bash syntax for "substring of `var` starting at `n` of length `m`."

If there can also be arbitrary subdirectories, either add `-r` to the `cp` command if you want to copy recursively or add a test to ignore directories in the `for` loop:

```
cd dir
for file in *; do
    if [ -f "$file" ]; then
        newpath="${file:0:1}/${file:1:1}"
        mkdir -p "$newpath"
        cp "$file" "$newpath"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Dang it! Same as my answer but quicker to get there.  You could add `2>/dev/null` on the `mkdir` so that you don't see errors when the directory already exists.

Comment: Only tweak would be `mkdir -p "$newpath" || { echo "directory creation failed '$newpath'"; break; }` Good solution.

Comment: This works perfectly.  I had no idea it could be this simple in a bash script.